# Loading Spark Context leads to Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:org.apache.spark.internal.config.TypedConfigBuilder.checkValu

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Hi I am creating a sparkSession in scala like below.

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").getOrCreate()
```

After running the app, i could see an exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.internal.config.TypedConfigBuilder.checkValue(Lscala/Function1;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/spark/internal/config/TypedConfigBuilder;
at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf$.<init>(SQLConf.scala:309)
at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf$.<clinit>(SQLConf.scala)
at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.StaticSQLConf$.<init>(StaticSQLConf.scala:31)
at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.StaticSQLConf$.<clinit>(StaticSQLConf.scala)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:940)
```

this is my build.sdt part.
Scala version is 2.11

```
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.4",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.4" exclude ("org.apache.parquet", "parquet-hadoop"),
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-catalyst" % "2.4.4",
```

Comment: post complete build.sbt file ??

Comment: Are running from IDE or on a cluster ?

Comment: @QuickSilver i am running from IDE

Comment: Is there any `ClassNotFoundException` at the bottom of your error stack trace ?

Comment: no, i didn't see ClassNotFoundException

Comment: Any update on that issue?

Comment: Ya, some other libraries are overriding spark version which is causing the issue.